# How can I use entity framework to get a count of database tables?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I've seen posts about MetadataWorkspace but no examples for this task. I want my code to detect if the database has had a new table added so I'm comparing the number of tables in the DB with 2 lists of known tables. A table can be either user data or system data and I want to delete all the data in the user tables.

If a new table is discovered, the code will ask the user to define whether it contains system or user data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should [help you](http://romiller.com/2012/04/20/what-tables-are-in-my-ef-model-and-my-database/).  Here is the relevant part of it for you:

```
var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

    var tables = metadata.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.SSpace)
      .GetItems<EntityContainer>()
      .Single()
      .BaseEntitySets
      .OfType<EntitySet>()
      .Where(s => !s.MetadataProperties.Contains("Type") 
        || s.MetadataProperties["Type"].ToString() == "Tables");
```

Comment: Awesome! Interestingly, it did not return __MigrationHistory but that's ok.

Comment: @BrianLeeming I believe that is because that part of the code queries against the EF model.  Take a look at the section of that article called "What about the database?".  That part might get you the migrationhistory